# Fetch latest tweet from specific user using twurl

Tags: api, twitter, console, tweets, twurl

I am attempting to fetch the latest tweet from a specific account with twurl so it can be done in the command prompt. I am not too familiar with the Twitter API which is why I'm asking. I don't belive there is any way to fetch the latest tweet without fetching all the tweets they have made for the past 5 days and filtering it out, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The latest Tweet is part of the User object so you should just be able to call `/1.1/users/show`

Answer (score -1):

1. First, you should authorize your twitter app and account with consumer API and secret keys.

- `twurl authorize -consumer-key <key> -consumer-secret <secret>`

2. Then can get the latest twitts of the specific user using [`GET statuses/user_timeline`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline).

- by screen_name :
  `twurl 1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=noradio&count=1`
- by user_id :
  `twurl 1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=12345&count=1`

Please refer to [twurl](https://github.com/twitter/twurl) for more information about requests.